# How to pass a variable to render?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

This is the line in my new.js.erb that calls the render function

```
$('.node_container').append("<%= escape_javascript(render(@care_point, :locals => {:care_map => @care_map}))%>");
```

Gives error message:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `care_map'
```

for my partial _care_point.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', [care_map, care_point], :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete, :remote => true, :class => 'delete' %>
```

Comment: Does this @care_map defined in your controller? (I mean in format.js block)

Comment: to pass `locals` variables, you must use `render :partial => ...` and not the mere `render @var`

Comment: @apneadiving - Put that in an answer please :)

Comment: yep done, thanks ;) PS: nice name!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass locals variables, you must use

```
render :partial => partial_name, :locals => { # all your vars here }
```

and not the mere:

```
render @var
```

See doc [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials), para `3.4.4`.

Comment: In Rails 3 you can actually just do: `render partial_name, :local1 => "thing", :local2 => "other"`, etc.  No need for the `:partial` or `:locals` bits ;)